# Spring boot cannot create datasource bean from cucumber test context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber

When running tests in a spring boot based application, spring is unable to create the datasource bean:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

Reading this error it is clear to me, I think, that spring did not read my application.properties file located at:

```
src/test/resources/application.properties
```

For clairity, I do not want to make use of an in memory database when running my integration tests, for application specific reasons.

This file contains:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.2.1:3306/project-test
spring.datasource.username=foo
spring.datasource.password=bar
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
```

While when starting the application using bootRun at does read out

```
src/main/resources/application.properties
```

and does create the datasource correctly.

My tests are based on cucumber and started using the following class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class AcceptanceTests {
}
```

The test context is started using the following annotations on a BaseSteps class which each class defining cucumber tests inherits from

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = App.class)
```

The spring context is started successfuly but it was unable to find my application.properties file and/or use it.

Comment: How is your `application.properties` file hookedup in your application?

Comment: Have you tried with `jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: @Craig that's what I'm trying to figure out, how does spring boot hook up the src/test/resources/application.properties file to my application.

Comment: @SaviNuclear I don't see how adding a property to my configuration file would help since clearly spring does not even find the file in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution.

I added changed the ContextConfiguration like so:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = App.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `ContextConfiguration`. This is needed for Spring-boot application tests.

Comment: When trying this I get: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required

Comment: @JonasGeiregat add `(classes = SampleDataJpaApplication.class)` after  `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`

Comment: I've also elaborated on how the tests are configured and started, might be important.